# Why AngularJS directives are preferred?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, dom-manipulation

DOM Manipulation and data binding can be done with Jquery also. What is the advantage of going with AngularJS Directives?

Comment: yes, it can be done inside the directives link function :)

Comment: directives are far more powerful than jquery.  
https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/jquery-angularjs-comparison-migration-walkthrough

Comment: Because someone else has already written the jquery for you, with unit-tests and 1000s of industry installations.   You think *your* code will be that robust?   More info here:  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/info

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest terms, a directive in AngularJS is a reusable component. Directives in AngularJS encapsulate all the behavioral properties and functionalities of an element in a semantic way, thereby keeping all of the functionality grouped together. This helps to keep track of changes of one HTML section in one place rather than tracking the changes on a global level in a script.

A more formal definition of a directive is: In AngularJS, a directive is a JavaScript factory function defined inside an AngularJS module that holds a set of instructions for the HTML compiler for defining a specified behavior of a DOM element.

A sample Directive Code

```
var myApp = angular.module(‘myApp’, []);
 myApp.directive(‘helloWorld’, function() {
    return {
        restrict: ‘E’,
template: ‘<h1>Hello World</h1>’
    };
});

<body ng-app=“myApp”>
    <hello-world></hello-world>
</body>
```

To know more about directive click the [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/)

Answer (score 0):

Angular js is two way binding so it will reduce writing more code. if any instance is changed then it will reflect everywhere in page